# Self-Concatenation in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am working on a string class structured with an `int` representing length and a `char*` for the data.  I have overridden the `+=` operator which works just fine, except when you try to self-concatenate, for example:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
s1 += s1;
cout << s1;
```

This returns: `À$p`
or other strange characters.  Here is my relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "assert.h"
using namespace std;

class String{
    public:
    int len;
    char *str;

    String()
    :len(0), str(nullptr){}

    String(char const* S)
    :len(strlen(S)), str(new char[len +1]){
        assert(S != 0);
        strcpy(str, S);
    }

    ~String(){
        delete[]str;
    }

    char* data() const{
        return this->str;
    }

    String operator +=(String const &S){
        int n = this->len + S.len;
        char * p = new char[n+1];
        strcpy(p + len, S.str);
        len = n;
        str = p;
        return *this;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, String const& str){
    return os << str.data();
}

int main()
{
    String g1 = "Hello";
    g1 += g1;
    cout << g1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just for notice: Your code leaks memory.

Comment: You also didn't copy the contents of the current buffer into the new buffer.

Comment: Your should really unit test your code before embarking on things such as working on overloading `+=`.  Just this simple `main` function shows that there is a problem `int main() {String s1("abc"); String s2 = s1;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with this code. First and foremost, review what the [Rule of Three/Five/Zero is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Now, there are three problems with the actual `operator+=`:

1. You're not actually copying the initial part of the string into `p`. You're just copying the second half. You'll want to do something like:

   ```
   memcpy(p, str, len);
   memcpy(p + len, S.str, S.len);
   ```
2. You're not cleaning the old contents. When you write `str = p;`, you just leaked the memory that `str` was pointing to. You need to write:

   ```
   delete [] str;
   ```

   before you do that assignment.
3. You're returning a temporary that gets immediately destroyed. The lack of copy constructor (see initial point) means that you are destroying `g1`'s buffer as a  result, and then you get a double free corruption error at the end of `main()` when you try to `delete[]` it again. This problem can be fixed by writing a valid copy constructor, but `operator+=` shouldn't be returning a temporary anyway - it should be returning a reference:

   ```
   String& operator+=(String const& S) { ... }
   ```